Unsupported url issue in swifui project
I am trying to build a very simple project in which I take input in a textbox and then let my django backend show it in console.
Code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var userInputText = ""

    func submitTextData() {
        guard let encodedText = userInputText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return }
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/?text=\(encodedText)") else { return }

        var components = URLComponents()
        components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: userInputText)]
        
        guard let encodedUrl = components.url else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: encodedUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error submitting data:", error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
                print("Text submitted successfully!")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Text", text: $userInputText)
            Button("Submit") {
                submitTextData()
            }
        }
    }
}

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Your components has the query item but doesn't have the rest of your url. You seem to be using two different ways to create the url. Try with url not encodedUrl

Note Apple requires https connection. To use http, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity"
in your Info.plist to allow http connection to the server. Have you done that? Show the full error message you get and on which line of the code. Try using var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!

I thought that local host was automatically allowed for http

AFAIK, “servers must support TLS 1.2 and forward secrecy, and certificates must be valid and signed using SHA256 or stronger with a minimum 2048-bit RSA key or 256-bit elliptic curve key. Network connections that don’t meet these requirements will fail unless the app overrides App Transport Security”.
